# PHP ARRAY, 2 foreach, input name=" " problem

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, loops, foreach

I need to list to all the schemas in some inputs (checkbox) then we can choose which one(s) we want to manipulate, to give privileges to a specific user.

Anyway, I got this, as you can see:

```php
<div id="list-schemas">
    <?php
        foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="schemas[]" value="' . $elt->getSchema() . '"/>' . $elt->getSchema() . '<br />';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Then, I need also to put some checkbox with the privileges, I did that:

```php
<div id="div-privileges">
    <?php
        foreach ($schemas as $elt) {
            echo '<div class="list">';
            echo '<label for="list">' . $elt->getSchema() . ' :</label><br />';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="REVOKE"/> REVOKE ? <br />';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="ALL"/> ALL PRIVILEGES ? <br />';
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="SELECT"/> SELECT ? <br />';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="INSERT"/> INSERT ? <br />';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="UPDATE"/> UPDATE ?  <br />';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="DELETE"/> DELETE ?  <br />';
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[]" value="CREATE"/>CREATE ?  <br />';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

So, that's being said, here's my function update in my UserManager.class.php :

```php
public static function update(User $newPerso){

    $db = DbConnect::getDb();
    $newLogin= pg_escape_string($newPerso->getLogin());
    $schemas=$newPerso->getSchemas();
    $privileges=$newPerso->getPrivileges();

    if (isset($schemas)){

        foreach($schemas as $schema){

            if (isset($privileges)){

                foreach($privileges as $privilege){

                    if($privilege=="REVOKE"){
                        pg_query("{$privilege} ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA {$schema} FROM {$newLogin};");
                    }

                    else if($privilege=="CREATE"){
                        pg_query("GRANT {$privilege} ON SCHEMA {$schema} TO {$newLogin};");
                    }
                    
                    else if($privilege=="ALL" || $privilege=="INSERT" || $privilege=="SELECT" || $privilege=="UPDATE" || $privilege=="DELETE"){
                        pg_query("GRANT {$privilege} ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA {$schema} TO {$newLogin};");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fact is that, it works, BUT,

When I choose for example 2 schemas, (let's say 'schema1' & 'schema2'),
& when I choose 'SELECT' for 'schema1' & 'INSERT' for 'schema2',

As result : The user will have 'SELECT' + 'INSERT' in 'schema1' & 'schema2'...

I'm really stuck, & I really don't know what to do actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify your inputs as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privileges[schema1][]" value="REVOKE"/> REVOKE ? <br />
```

See this `[schema1]`? It will give you another level in `$_POST` array.

And therefore you can iterate over it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['privileges'] as $schema => $privileges) {
    foreach ($privileges as $privilege) {
        // you know what privilege is for what schema
    }
}
```

Comment: Well @u_mulder, thank you very very much for your help !

In fact, it works !

But I did some tests & I got a last problem.
As you can see, If I do that :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/37/3/1568186255-capture.png

My User will have (in that example) : ALL PRIVILEGES in both of these schemas...

Comment: I can't see what you do to get such output. So it's better to ask a new question and provide excerpt of code which generates such output.

Comment: Yes, I will do that, anyway @u_mulder thank you so much for your time.